# Sorting JSON data based on key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following json:

```
{'2019-05-01': 5423.66, '2019-05-02': 5503.3017, '2019-05-03': 5775.8817, '2019-05-04': 5876.01, '2019-05-05': 5823.795}
```

I would like to have an outcome like this, sorted by the key:

```
2019-05-05  5823.795
2019-05-04  5876.01
2019-05-03  5775.8817
2019-05-02  5503.3017
2019-05-01  5423.66
```

So far I have the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime

data = {'2019-05-01': 5423.66, '2019-05-02': 5503.3017, '2019-05-03': 5775.8817, '2019-05-04': 5876.01, '2019-05-05': 5823.795}
d = sorted(data, reverse=True)

for i in data:
    bip_date = datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d")
    bip_price = data[i] 
    print(bip_date, bip_price)
```

I always get the error message:
"bip_price = data[i] list indices must be integers or slices, not str" Any ideas?

Comment: It works perfectly well on my computer; did you clean your variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort and print the dict items directly:

```
data = {'2019-05-01': 5423.66, '2019-05-02': 5503.3017, '2019-05-03': 5775.8817, '2019-05-04': 5876.01, '2019-05-05': 5823.795}

for k, v in sorted(data.items(), reverse=True):
    print(k, v)
```

Prints:

```
2019-05-05 5823.795
2019-05-04 5876.01
2019-05-03 5775.8817
2019-05-02 5503.3017
2019-05-01 5423.66
```